# How to upload nodejs project/website on hostgator. Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am going to upload my website by using hostgator. Is it possible OR IF Yes then please give me the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy nodejs application to hostgator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194832/how-to-deploy-nodejs-application-to-hostgator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read [this](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/node-js)
If you are not in really need for hostgator only, You can use 
heroku or AWS (amazon web services) or digital ocean platforms to host your application and their documentations are very easy to understand by reading 
try them if yor are interested

here for nodejs on heroku [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs). they have a tour like guide for you to deploy your app easily just follow their steps and its free for one application